# prove bijectiveness: $f(i,j)=\frac{(i+j-2)(i+j-1)}{2}+i$, how to approach this problem?

Tags: functions, problem-solving

Let $f:\mathbb{Z}^+\times\mathbb{Z}^+\to\mathbb{Z}^+$ be defined by $f(i,j)=\frac{(i+j-2)(i+j-1)}{2}+i$.

How can I prove that this function is bijective? I tried to find an inverse by playing around with the equation $y=\frac{(i+j-2)(i+j-1)}{2}+i$ and trying to solve for $i$ and $j$, but I couldn't. In general, is it possible to solve for two variables if you have just one equation? When is it not possible?

Comment: $f(1,1) = 1$, $f(1,2) = 1$. So how is this bijective?

Comment: @sku $f(1,2)=2$

Comment: oh damn.... yes

Comment: The map closely resembles Cantor's diagonalisation. To prove it is bijective formally should be doable. You need to prove it is injective and surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

| $i\ \smallsetminus \ j$ | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | $\dots$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 7 | 11 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 | 8 | 12 | $\ddots$ |
| 3 | 6 | 9 | 13 | $\ddots$ |  |
| 4 | 10 | 14 | $\ddots$ |  |  |
| $\vdots$ | 15 | $\ddots$ |  |  |  |

Try proving that each set $\{f(i,j)\mid i + j = k\}$ is equal to $\{T_{k-2} + 1, T_{k - 2} + 2,\dots,T_{k-1}\}$ where $T_{k} = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ is the $k$th triangular number.

Comment: Does this prove the function is bijective? If yes, how?